# what exactly is biasing in transistors and how to do biasing

Tags: transistors, npn, bias

I have read that collector, emitter must be reverse biased in CE configuration in npn transistor but how can n and n be reverse biased

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear what you read, but the conditions for forward active operation of an npn transistor are

$$V_{be} > V_f$$

$$V_{ce} \ge V_{ce}(\mathrm{sat})$$

\$V_f\$ is typically around 0.6 or 0.7 V and  \$V_{ce}(\mathrm{sat})\$ is typically around 0.2 V.

Some texts will say that \$ V_{ce} > V_{be}\$ is required for forward active operation, and this is a reasonable rule to ensure that a reasonable output signal can be achieved without distortion. But the transition from forward-active to saturation is fuzzy, so either rule could be used, depending on what behavior is under discussion.

That is, the base-emitter junction must be strongly forward biased, and the collector must be biased at least slightly above the emitter.

But there is no junction between the collector and emitter regions, so it doesn't particularly make sense to talk about whether they're "forward" or "reverse" biased relative to each other.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is true that for "linear" amplification purposes it is required that Vce>Vbe. As a consequence, the base-collector pn junction will be reverse biased with Vc>Vb (I assume, it was this condition you have read somewhere). Only under this condition the carriers (electrons in case of npn) which are set free at the emitter - if Vbe>(0.6...0.7)V - are able to move through the base region to the collector, thuis forming the current Ic.

Answer (score 0):

The actual design is *NPN* where the middle "P" is the base. The base-collector is reverse biased.

**Mental picture time**: if you forward bias the base-emitter, just a little, *some electrons* will flow from emitter to base. However, since the base junction is *Quite Thin*, several of those electrons will "overshoot" the target...
ending up in the Collector. Which is reverse biased.

As a result, these errant overshoot electrons are pushed *away* from the base, causing collector current.